# How to cancel a previously scheduled event in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scheduled-tasks, nstimer

I am making an iphone app and have scheduled an event called gameOver to occur after 15 seconds(when the game is over).

```
[self performSelector:@selector(gameOver) withObject:nil afterDelay:15.0];
```

How can I unschedule this event so that if someone wanted to press a reset button and start the game over, this scheduled event would be deleted and another one would be created.

Answer (score 4):

I would use an [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

with the `retain`-property `NSTimer *myTimer`

```
-(void) startTimer
{
    self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:myDelay target:self selector:@selector(myTimerExpiredMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
-(void) myTimerExpiredMethod:(id)aSender
{
     NSLog(@"timer expired");
     self.myTimer = nil;
}
-(void) cancelTimer
{
    [self.myTimer invalidate];
    self.myTimer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget
```

aTarget would be the object the selector should be performed on. self in your example.

Edit: 
This method is defined on NSObject so:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:myObject]
```

would be the syntax.

Edit 2: 
Use

```
+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument
```

to only unschedule calls to this specific selector.

Comment: The object passed to the `withObject:` parameter would be the single parameter to be passed to the selector in question; it's not the target here. The target in the OP's case is `self`. If the OP wanted to cancel this, they could just `[[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]`.